# In Vertx webclient how to log http request and response

Tags: vert.x

What is the simplest way for logging outgoing http request and response in Vertx WebClient. I'm looking for something similar to the httpserver LoggerHandler, but then for the webclient thus outgoing requests.

Answer (score 5):

`WebClient` has an overloaded `create(Vertx, WebClientOptions)` method.

`WebClientOptions` has a [`setLogActivity()`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClientOptions.html#setLogActivity-boolean-) method that accepts a boolean parameter that indicates if network activity should be logged.

(disclaimer: i haven't tried this myself so i can't vouch for what's actually logged, but see if that covers your needs).

Comment: Yes, that works but the logging is not simply the request and response. It comes from netty and seems hardly human readable so I was hoping for something better.

Comment: if the logger observes any logging configuration you supply, maybe you can suppress the extraneous stuff that way.